# Good android network practice

Tags: android

I'm currently developing a game for android. This game has heavy networking.

Is it better to have two separate threads, one for receiving messages and the other for sending messages. Or is it better to have a single thread for sending and receiving messages?

```
public static void init(String h){
    host=h;
    connected=false;
    instance = new Client();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
            try{
                bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
                        .group(group)
                        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                        .handler(instance);

                channel = bootstrap.connect(host,PORT).sync().channel();
                connected=true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (notifier!=null){
                    notifier.onServerNoLongerReachable();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public static void setNotifier(ClientInterface notif){
    notifier = notif;
}
```

I'm using Netty and I have a custom interface that my activities implement

```
public interface ClientInterface{
    void onReceive(String msg);
    void onServerNoLongerReachable();
}
```

Comment: One thread per message would be ideal, but what issues are you currently experiencing to prompt the question? And are you using `RxJava`, because that would aid in the network requests.

Comment: I'm currently not experiencing any issues, I'm just verifying that I'm not going about it in the wrong way.

Comment: Can you provide any code as an example?

Answer (score 0):

Using Thread is NOT a good practice for Android Dev.
Use Asynctask is better : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Or as Cricket_007 you should take a look at RxJava : https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid

For networkCall, you could use Retrofit w/ RxJava:
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, though, because 1) AsyncTask needs to carefully handle Socket / Channel communications. 2) `NioEventLoopGroup` in the question would need to have an Rx equivalent, so just pointing at the documentation wouldn't help there